# Open url in Detailview

Tags: ios, detailsview, tfhpple

I'm using tfhpple to parse a HTML page. I am parsing this part :

```
<li>                   
    <a title ="Return Kuban Krasnodar om 21.00 uur (87 reacties)" href="nieuws/23271-return-kuban-krasnodar-om-21-00-uur.html">
```

I am displaying it in a tableview like this: http://tinypic.com/r/4so5yp/5

But I'm wondering if I can use the `href` to use that url to display the text on that page in my detailview, cause I'm making an news app. Is that possible?

This is how i parse the html and get all the titles in my tableview. i also retrieve all the href's which contains the url that contains the text i want to display in my detailview. :

```
   import "Fr12ListViewController.h"
   import "Fr12Cell.h"
   import "Fr12Opslag.h"
   import "TFHpple.h"
   import "Fr12DetailViewController.h"

   @interface Fr12ListViewController ()

   @end

  @implementation Fr12ListViewController
  @synthesize Fr12Content;

-(void)loadFr12Feed {
  // 1

NSURL *Fr12WebsiteLink = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.fr12.nl/"];
NSData *Fr12WebsiteHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:Fr12WebsiteLink];

//
TFHpple *Fr12WebsiteParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:Fr12WebsiteHtmlData];

// 3
 NSString *Fr12WebsiteXpathQueryString = @"//div[@class ='content_left_extra']/ul/li/a";
  NSArray *Fr12WebsiteNodes = [Fr12WebsiteParser searchWithXPathQuery:Fr12WebsiteXpathQueryString];

// 4
 NSMutableArray *newFr12Website = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
 for (TFHppleElement *element in Fr12WebsiteNodes) {
    // 5
    Fr12Opslag *fr12opslag = [[Fr12Opslag alloc] init];
    [newFr12Website addObject:fr12opslag];

    // 6
    fr12opslag.title = [element objectForKey:@"title"];


    // 7
    bowtiefulimages.url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];



}

// 8
Fr12Content = newFr12Website;
[self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIWebView in your detailView and parse this url and use this method:

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourLink"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];
    [webview loadRequest:request];
```

**UPDATED:**
if you want to get contents of that url then you can use:

```
stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
```

of NSString. Then you can have the text in its content by parsing the obtained data.

Comment: i think i wasn't clear, i already parsed the website www.fr12.nl to get all the titles into my tableview, but i also parse the href to get a url, which holds the text of the article that i want to display in my detailview. I don't want to use a Uiwebview, i just want it to be a news app, with article name in tableview, and article text in detailview. But thanks for your help so far ! @Krishna Kumar

Comment: if you have the text to display in your detailView, then what is your problem... And if the text will be loaded after going on respective urls then you can use web view to display it.. Please explain exactly what you want to do..

Comment: im using this for the thpple NSString *Fr12WebsiteXpathQueryString = @"//div[@class ='content_left_extra']/ul/li/a"; So i get  all the title and the html, the title i display in a tableview. But i need the Text within the html from the href. thats ifferent. And i'm wondering if that's even possible. I need to parse the parsed url so to speak.

Comment: You want to extract url or content of that url which is not available in present html content?? Please clarify..

Comment: i want to extract content of i url which i reaceive after parsing the a tag for 'href'. Because the main url i use is the homepage of the newspage ( www.fr12.nl) and i get all the articles names, but i want the article content displayed in my detailview. So i parse fr12.nl to get an url, but then i want the content of the url i received.

Comment: i do not understand your edit, i am confused because i already parsed the html to receive a url, but than from what i understand i have to use that url to put in in the webview to get the text that i need? p.s. i also edited my question @krishna kumar

Comment: I mean a news app like this : http://blackberry.github.io/Cascades-Samples/rssnews.html but with tfhpple instead of Json @Krishna Kumar